# How to create graphics in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I was wondering about how is possible to make graphics in a programming language just like Java, I mean in the web there are HTML + CSS etc but what here?

I already found out I might start to code with Java Swing (?) but if that's so: where's the best place to start learning it and really briefly: what can I do with that?

Please, note I don't want to start a broad talk with this question, so don't worry and be brief if you don't want to spen too many words with it ;)

Comment: Google for "swing tutorial".

Comment: And is that the only way to make graphics with Java? @JBNizet

Comment: Or look at [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) in the link that's in the [tag:swing] tag in your question above. It contains links to the tutorials and then some.

Comment: No, there is also JavaFX, and eclipse's SWT toolkit.

Comment: What you think is the best one, yeah IYHO? @JBNizet

Comment: I only know one of them, so I can't provide an informed advice.

Comment: That's alright, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For graphics you can use a Canvas/JPanel with Swing, JavaFX, or libGDX if you need a bit more power behind your graphics as it used OpenGL.

As some of the other commenters have already shown, there are many tutorials on how to use all three options, so you're pretty-well set to learn whichever you choose. I'm not entirely sure how well JavaFX deals with graphics, but Swing works perfectly fine for most purposes.